# How to show progress bar in with spring controller and thymleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, progress-bar, thymeleaf

I am sending SMS using api call to about 100+ users. Each api call requires around 1 second each. So while the 100+ api calls are made, I want to show some progress bar? This is a Spring boot application. I am calling the api from the controller. So, what i want to do is reflecting the amount of api call so far in the front end. Can this be done using Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ResponseBodyEmitter`. See the examples [here](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-mvc-responsebodyemitter.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your front end keep a variable that increment after every successful api call happen. use that variable to update the progress bar

Comment: This might actually lead to performance degradation.